# Change the value of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, for-loop

i hope you can help me.
The thing is that i don't know how to change the value of a variable, for example, i have a 
"char" variable and then i wanna change it to "int" or "float"
This is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

main()
{
{
cout<<" El valor de las calificaciones es A=10,B=9,C=8,D=7,E=6,F=5,G=4,H=3,I=2,J=1 "             <<endl;}
char calificaciones[4];
int resultado,A=10,B=9,C=8,D=7,E=6,F=5,G=4,H=3,I=2,J=1, i, promedio;
for(i=1;i<4;i++)

{

    cout<<"Ingrese calificacion con letra "<<i;
    cin>>calificaciones[i];


}
promedio=(calificaciones[1]+calificaciones[2]+calificaciones[3])/3;
cout<<"El promedio de sus tres calificaciones es "<<promedio<<endl;
system("pause");

}
```

The program is supposed to ask for the user to enter three scores and the scores are shown in letters as you can see, A=10, B=9, etc, and once the user enters three letters the program is going to divide them into three, but since the variable "calificaciones" was a string first, how do i make the operation i want to do this, or whats the command that i could use for the program to understand that the user entered three letters and an operation will be made with them?
Hope you can help me and thanks.

Comment: "i have a "string" variable" where?

Comment: You're not talking about changing the *value* of a variable, you're talking about changing it's type. That's really not how most languages work. You don't change a type, you convert a value of one type into a new value of a different type, and store it in a *different* variable.

Comment: I understood that you want the user to type e.g. "A", "E" and "F" and then you need to use the respective variables. You should use a std::map, so you have std::map["A"] = 10, and so on, then if you have somestring=="A" you get access by doing std::map[somestring]

Comment: man, why are you not using python ? C++ at your level is not the fastest way to learn.

Comment: It might be homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original question is, how to change `datatype`, sorry that is not possible.

Although, what you are trying to achieve can be done by `std::map`

Create Map of your grades.

```
 std::map<char,int> myGrades;
 myGrades.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('A',10) );
 myGrades.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('B',9) );
 myGrades.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('C',8) );
 myGrades.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('D',7) );
```

Read input: (this is same. only change is index starts from 0)

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    cout<<"Ingrese calificacion con letra "<<i;
    cin>>calificaciones[i];
}
```

Get actual integers from map.

```
int total_grades =  ( myGrades.find(calificaciones[0])->second + 
                      myGrades.find(calificaciones[1])->second + 
                      myGrades.find(calificaciones[2])->second);
promedio=total_grades /3.0;  //<-- NOtice 3.0 to avoid int/int
```

Comment: Why the downvote? (Wasn't me!) I was just about to post an answer along the same lines as this. (I would have said mapValueOfLetter['A'] = 10; but same general idea).

Comment: @MarkU but the way I have explained is correct.. Any improvement you would like to have?

Comment: I agree, this looks like a correct, valid, and useful answer. Perhaps the first two or three sentences sound negative?  I'll upvote this, best I can do for you. Sorry man.

Comment: Yes, this solution is solid. I'm guessing it's the use of maps? He doesn't understand how datatypes work, let alone associative containers.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to change the datatype of a variable in strongly-typed languages like C++, Java, etc. You'll need to define a new variable with the desired type instead. Weakly-typed languages like Python and PHP are (generally) typeless and will let you mix and match datatypes however you like, but it's not possible in C++. You can technically use [**void pointers**](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/) to point to objects of any type, but they don't let you change the type of existing  variables. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) is more information on strong and weak typing.

If you're okay with creating a new variable, you can use conversion functions or manually convert between datatypes (if possible). For example, it's not possible to convert the string "Hello world" to an int, but you *can* change a string like "42" to an int. The `cstdlib` / `stdlib.h` header provides functions like [`atof()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) and [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) which can do basic conversions (make sure you convert any C++ strings to character arrays using `myString.c_str()` before passing them). [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is also a very powerful tool which easily converts practically anything to a string, among other uses.

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but you can use the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values of the characters to convert them. For example, the letter `A` has the ASCII value of 65, `B` is 66, `C` is 67, and so on. Because characters are inherently stored as numbers, you can convert them without using special conversion functions. You can simply assign a char to an int:

```
char ch = 'A';
int x = ch;           // this is an implicit conversion
cout << x << endl;    // this prints '65'
```

The character is being [**cast**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) to an integer. You can also explicitly convert it:

```
char ch = 'A';
cout << ch << endl;        // this prints 'A'
cout << (int) ch << endl;  // this prints '65' because of the explicit conversion
```

It also works the other way around:

```
int x = 65;
char ch = x;
cout << ch << endl;   // this prints 'A'
```